# Is iPhone 6/6 Plus support required for iOS app updates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am working on an update to my iOS app and am wondering if I need to support the iPhone 6/6 Plus screen sizes within my app in order for the update to be approved by Apple. Are their guidelines and/or deadlines for when iPhone 6/6 Plus optimization is required?

My app looks and works fine when the new devices auto-scale to fill the screen, so I'm trying to find out if I have to spend the time optimizing.

Comment: Nothing published, but start thinking of getting it optimized - the day will probably come.

Comment: Why wouldn't you support the larger screen? It will improve your sales. As the owner of an iPhone 6/6+, I'd buy an app that supports my bigger screen over an app that doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only requirement I'm aware of is:

*Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.* -- [source](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a)

So, no, it's not required to support iPhone 6/6+ yet, if it ever will be requirement.

Comment: I'd expect it to be a requirement no more than a year from the 64-bit requirement.

Comment: Depends on what they'll announce next year. It's Apple, never expect anything and you'll be happy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't required to update your apps for the iPhone 6 and the iPhone 6 Plus.

But: It's very likely that Apple will make the iPhone 6 support obligatory in early 2015, as well as they have done it with the iPhone 5 and the latest iOS releases like iOS 7 in early 2014 and iOS 8 starting February 1, 2015.

It's possible that the support for the latest iPhones will be an obligation in a few months as well, so you should begin right now to update your apps.